# Quering by nested object in mongoose and nestjs

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I `Label` document which is nested inside `Product` document.

Now i trying to find all documents where Label has some name but instead of array of objects this array is empty.

What im using to get docs

```
return this.productModel.find({
      'label.name': 'Something',
    });
```

`LabelSchema.ts`

```
@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class Label extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true })
  user: User;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, default: null })
  email: string | null;

  @Prop({ type: String, default: null })
  description: string;

  @Prop({ type: SocialSchema, default: new Social() })
  socials: Social;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: LabelStatus, default: LabelStatus.Draft })
  status: string;

  // TODO add FILE document
  @Prop({ type: String, default: null })
  avatar: any;

  // TODO add FILE document
  @Prop({ type: String, default: null })
  header: any;

  @Prop({
    type: Number,
    default: process.env.APP_DEFAULT_COMMISSION_RATE,
  })
  commissionRate: number;

  @Prop({ type: Number, default: 0 })
  earnings: number;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  slug: string;

  @Prop({ type: Date, required: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop({ type: Date, required: true })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

`ProductSchema.ts`

```
@Schema({
  versionKey: false,
  timestamps: true,
})
export class Product extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: ProductStatus, default: ProductStatus.Draft })
  status: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: Label.name,
    autopopulate: true,
  })
  label: Label;

  @Prop({ type: String, default: '' })
  shortDescription: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, default: '' })
  description: string;

  @Prop({ type: Number, default: null })
  price: number | null;

  @Prop({ type: Number, default: null })
  salePrice: number | null;

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false })
  isFree: boolean;

  //TODO add FILE document
  artwork: any;

  //TODO add FILE document
  audioPreview: any;

  @Prop([
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Category.name,
      autopopulate: true,
    },
  ])
  category: Category[];

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false })
  featured: false;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  slug: string;

  @Prop({ type: Date, required: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop({ type: Date, required: true })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your label is an `ObjectId` while on the product model, so you can only query it by `ObjectId`. There are a few ways to solve this. The most ideal would be to look up by `ObjectId` directly instead of by name (e.g. if this is coming from the client, and they are selecting the label, have the client send the labels id, not the labels name).

If that isn't possible, I'd recommend first looking up the label.

```
const label = await labelModel.findOne({name: 'Something'}, {_id: 1})
const products = await productModel.find({label: label._id})
```

Comment: Ok i had this idea in my mind but i thought that might be overcomplicated